# Search and delete a block using sed command in ubuntu

Tags: bash, vim, sed, vi, replace

The thing I would like to perform is to 1- Find and 2- delete the whole definition block of (__c64):

```
unsigned long long __c64(unsigned int llvm_cbe_hi, unsigned int llvm_cbe_lo) {
unsigned long long llvm_cbe_retval;    /* Address-exposed local */
unsigned long long llvm_cbe_retval1;



  *(&llvm_cbe_retval) = (((((unsigned long long )(unsigned int )llvm_cbe_hi)) << 32ul) |  (((unsigned          long long )(unsigned int )llvm_cbe_lo)));
  llvm_cbe_retval1 = *(&llvm_cbe_retval);
  return llvm_cbe_retval1;
}
```

in all but one .c files in a project.  Since in the compilation phase of .o to the executable,  I got the error "Multiple definition of __c64", I was thinking to delete all of those but one in order to solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Regards,

Amir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys as I found the definitions were dynamically changed, I tried to figure out sth like :

```
sed '/^unsigned long long __c64/,/}/d'
```

and it did fortunately work.

Thanks for all the helps.

Amir

Answer (score 0):

If function layout is exactly same in all files you can try this

```
gvim -p *.c    // Open all relevant files in multiple tabs
```

then execute this

```
:bufdo %s/unsigned long long __c64\(.\+\n\)\+\(\n\)\+\(.\+\n\)\+}// | update
```

"update" executed at the end will save each file.

Comment: thanks for the reply, don't we have any bash scripts like   "sed -i s/" which I can put in the middle of the compilation phase in order to do it automatically ?

Comment: :by the way, does it like deleting the first 3 line or all the 6 line block ?? cuz i can see only see three \n\ ?

Comment: That is what '+' is for.It will delete the entire block ending at the closing brace.

Comment: thanks I got it. but why I can't use this script in bash with sed like : sed -i 's/unsigned long long __c64\(.\+\n\)\+\(\n\)\+\(.\+\n\)\+}//' "$f" . It doesn't change anything :|

Comment: As I check it has to be with the difference of sed reading line by line, so I think I am gonna need of another command for performing the task, right?